# All Browsers seem to ignore JavaScript Client Side form validation rule

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I've used JavaScript to ensure that the fields on my form are correctly filled out (required fields with correct type of information) and the browser seems to ignore the rules I set and process the information anyway.

HTML

```
HTML



 <form id="course-form" name="courseForm" method="POST" onSubmit="return checkCourse()" action="#">
        <label for="courseName">Course Name: </label>
        <input type="text" id="course-name" name="courseName" placeholder="Course Name" required/><br/>
        <br>
        <label for="qualDesc">Description: </label><br/>
        <textarea name="qualDesc" class="boxsizingBorder" placehold
        <label for="entryReqs">Entry Requirements</label><br>
        <textarea name="entryReqs" class="boxsizingBorder" id="entry-reqs" placeholder="Previous Grades Required" required></textarea><br>
        <br>
        <label for="cost">Cost: &pound;</label>
        <input type="text" name="cost" id="courseCost" maxlength="6" size="5" required/><br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Add Course" />
</form>
```

JavaScript(Placed in Head of document)

```
        <script>
        function checkCourse()
        {
            var date = new Date();
            var year = (date.getFullYear());            
            var courseName=document.forms["courseForm"]["courseName"].value;
            var courseDesc=document.forms["courseForm"]["qualDesc"].value;
            var courseYear=document.forms["courseForm"]["year"].value;
            var entryReqs=document.forms["courseForm"]["entryReqs"].value;
            var cost=document.forms["courseForm"]["cost"].value;

            if(courseName == "")
            {
                alert("Course name is a required field.");
                return false;
            }
            else if(courseDesc=="")
            {
                alert("The Course needs a description");
                return false;
            }
            else if(courseYear < year)
            {
                alert("The academic year for " + courseYear + " has already commenced. \n Please pick a later date);
                return false;
            }
            else if(entryReqs=="")
            {
                alert("You must enter some entry requirements");
                return false;
            }
            else if(isNaN(cost) || (cost==""))
            {
                alert("Cost is not a valid numerical figure");
            }

            alert("Course added sucessfully!");
            return true;

        }
    </script>
```

**Note, I've also tried putting the return true section in an else statement like this:

```
else
{
  alert("Course added sucessfully!");
  return true;
}
```

Am I missing something?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the line below, you try to get the value of an input, but your form does not contain an input that is named `year`. This will cause a Javascript error and subsequently, your validation will be disregarded and the form will continue to submit

```
var courseYear=document.forms["courseForm"]["year"].value;
```

A second problem is you don't `return false` if the cost validation fails (but this is not your root problem).

Also as juvian points out, you are missing a closing quote on the alert below:

```
alert("The academic year for " + courseYear + " has already commenced. \n Please pick a later date);
```

Comment: Yeah he is also missing a " in an alert

Comment: Good spot, added to answer.

Comment: Also, HTML is invalid, one opened textarea which isn't closed: <textarea name="qualDesc" class="boxsizingBorder" placehold. It is causing another javascript error: var entryReqs=document.forms["courseForm"]["entryReqs"].value; -> this is undefined